# How to use Glade 3.22

Tags: gtk, glade

I'm trying to create my first application using GTK and I can create the GtkApplicationWindow and then a GtkMenuBar and set it so it only fills the top of the window.

I cannot edit the menu nor add anything else.  GtkStatusBar is gone, and using GtkBox or anything else results in an error that "Widgets of type X need placeholders to add children"?  So is that it?  Am I only allowed to choose between a menubar or a statusbar and use nothing else?

I'm a Microsoft Windows guy, but I'm trying to expand my horizons on Linux but I'm ready to throw the laptop in the trash.
Ideally, I'd like a GtkApplicationWindow that has a menubar on top, some kind of frame in the middle, and a statusbar below.  Also, is there a way to add resources to a CodeBlocks project (icons, bitmaps, etc), or is that strictly a Windows construct?

I don't have any code to give, because I'm just starting with this program.

Comment: If this is really your first GTK application, I'd recommend NOT using glade. [This](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html) is a good place to start. For resources you will need some extra work(read description [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gresource-tool.html) and after that [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GResource.html) carefully!)

Comment: Glade seems to work, I'm just learning about GtkWindow only having one parent, unlike Ms Windows where a window can have x,000 child controls.

Comment: I try to center this window and I fail miserably

Comment: gtk_window_set_decorated (GTK_WINDOW (pAppWidgets->pSplashScreen), FALSE);
        gtk_widget_hide (GTK_WIDGET (pAppWidgets->pSplashScreen));
        gtk_widget_realize((GtkWidget *)pAppWidgets->pSplashScreen);
        gtk_window_set_gravity (GTK_WINDOW (pAppWidgets->pSplashScreen), GDK_GRAVITY_CENTER);
        gtk_window_move(GTK_WINDOW(pAppWidgets->pSplashScreen), 600, 600);
        gtk_window_set_position (pAppWidgets->pSplashScreen, GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
        gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET (pAppWidgets->pSplashScreen));

Comment: GtkWindow itself can contain only one child (it is subclassed from GtkBin, [see here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#GtkWindow.object-hierarchy)). But you can put there _another_ container, which can hold more than one children (GtkBox, GtkGrid).